# grammar problem - can we say that

Tags: grammar

Can we say that: "When you are my age *you will have known* all about this?" For me this is the first conditional and it should be "When you are my age, you will know all about this." Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

The verb "know" describes a state.  You can use perfect aspect with such verb only when describing a time continuing to the present

> I have known all about this for five years.  (okay)

> I have known all about this  (odd)

Instead you say "I know all about this".

So it would be okay to say:

> When you are my age you will have known all about this for five years

But without the time phrase, the expression is odd, and it would be better to use

> When you are my age you will know all about this

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with 'When you are my age, you will have known passion, joy, sadness, and boredom, failure and success. You will be ready to retire.'

Comment: Yes, that would be possible.  But the use of future is the red herring here.  You can say "I have known passion and joy".  But "I have known maths" seems odd.  Putting that into the future doesn't change anything.